# Enable right click (open new window) in the suggestions menu in jqueryui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a jqueryui autocomplete widget in which the listings in the suggestions menu are clickable links.

Now, left clicking on the links works fine, but the browser (I'm using chrome but this issue is probably not browser-specific) is not providing an option to right click the link to open a new window.

My question is how would I go about to enable the links in the suggestions menu right clickable?

In the jqueryui autocomplete code within the _renderItem() method, it has

```
_renderItem = function( ul, item ){ ... .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>"
```

Maybe the reason that right click is deactivated is because the <a> tag does not have a href attribute? I don't really have the ability to add a href attribute with the actual url as I have a select event handler that dynamically generates the url based on other logic. Also, when I tried to add a href attribute to the <a> tag, jqueryui seems to be auto-removing it when the suggestions menu is populated.

Comment: Right clicking and selecting "open new window" is provided by the browser natively (and it appears your hunch was correct; the `href` attribute makes it appear in some browsers). Your select handler will not be run if you manage to make that menu show up. Are you interested in using your own right-click menu?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am now able to get the href= to be defined so right click does work now. However, I am running into a new problem: If the suggestions menu is opened, and I right click on one of the items to open a new window, the suggestions menu in the current window can no longer be opened be clicking elsewhere on the screen. Any insight on how this can be fixed?